# Button that leads to another screen/page in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, navigation

i'am fairly new to react native and i'm doing a social media clone. I've got my navigator and the login via a database done , but i was wondering if there was a way to link a page/screen to another one by pressing a button .
Here is my code for the home screen after logging in :

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Text, FlatList} from 'react-native';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

class HomeScreen extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      isLoading: true,
      listData: []
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.unsubscribe = this.props.navigation.addListener('focus', () => {
      this.checkLoggedIn();
    });
  
    this.getData();
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unsubscribe();
  }

  getData = async () => {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@session_token');
    return fetch("http://localhost:3333/api/1.0.0/search", {
          'headers': {
            'X-Authorization':  value
          }
        })
        .then((response) => {
            if(response.status === 200){
                return response.json()
            }else if(response.status === 401){
              this.props.navigation.navigate("Login");
            }else{
                throw 'Something went wrong';
            }
        })
        .then((responseJson) => {
          this.setState({
            isLoading: false,
            listData: responseJson
          })
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        })
  }

  checkLoggedIn = async () => {
    const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('@session_token');
    if (value == null) {
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Login');
    }
  };

  render() {

    if (this.state.isLoading){
      return (
        <View
          style={{
            flex: 1,
            flexDirection: 'column',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            alignItems: 'center',
          }}>
          <Text>Loading..</Text>
        </View>
      );
    }else{







      
      return (

        
         
        <View

        
        style={{
          flex: 1,
          justifyContent: 'center',
          alignItems: 'center',
        }}>
        <Text>Welcome to The app </Text>
      </View>

        
      );
    }
    
  }
}



export default HomeScreen;
```

Now ideally i would want a button in my else statement which could lead me to another screen (eg main screen of the app ) after logging in .

App.js :

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createDrawerNavigator } from '@react-navigation/drawer';

import HomeScreen from './screens/home';
import LoginScreen from './screens/login';
import SignupScreen from './screens/signup';
import LogoutScreen from './screens/logout';

const Drawer = createDrawerNavigator();

class App extends Component{
    render(){
        return (
            <NavigationContainer>
                <Drawer.Navigator initialRouteName="Home">
                    <Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
                    <Drawer.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
                    <Drawer.Screen name="Signup" component={SignupScreen} />
                    <Drawer.Screen name="Logout" component={LogoutScreen} />
                </Drawer.Navigator>
                
            </NavigationContainer>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Provide an `onClick` handler for the button as usual, and call `this.props.navigation.navigate('...')` inside

Comment: Also note that you can do `<View style={{ ... }}>{ this.state.isLoading ? <Text>Loading..</Text> : <Text>Welcome to The app </Text>}</View>`

Answer (score 0):

If you're new to react native, I'd suggest that you give functional components and hooks a try, this is how your code would look like as a functional component after some clean up

(The answer is included in  component)

```
import React, { Component, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { View, Text, FlatList, Button } from "react-native";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";

const HomeScreen = (props) => {
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);
    const [listData, setListData] = useState([]);

    useEffect(() => {
        const subscription = props.navigation.addListener("focus", () => {
            checkLoggedIn();
        });
        getData();
        return subscription.remove(); //similar to component unmount, syntax might be different based on your version
    }, []);

    const getData = async () => {
        setIsLoading(true)
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@session_token");
        return fetch("http://localhost:3333/api/1.0.0/search", {
            headers: {
                "X-Authorization": value,
            },
        })
            .then((response) => {
                if (response.status === 200) {
                    return response.json();
                } else if (response.status === 401) {
                    props.navigation.navigate("Login");
                } else {
                    throw "Something went wrong";
                }
            })
            .then((responseJson) => {
                setIsLoading(false);
                setListData(responseJson);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
    };

    const checkLoggedIn = async () => {
        const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem("@session_token");
        if (value == null) {
            props.navigation.navigate("Login");
        }
    };

    return (
        <>
            {isLoading ? (
                <View
                    style={{
                        flex: 1,
                        flexDirection: "column",
                        justifyContent: "center",
                        alignItems: "center",
                    }}
                >
                    <Text>Loading..</Text>
                </View>
            ) : (
                <View
                    style={{
                        flex: 1,
                        justifyContent: "center",
                        alignItems: "center",
                    }}
                >
                    <Text>Welcome to The app </Text>
                    <Button
                        title="Next Page"
                        onPress={() => {
                            props.navigation.navigate("yourScreenName");
                        }}
                    />
                </View>
            )}
        </>
    );
};

export default HomeScreen;
```

since you screens are

```
<Drawer.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} />
<Drawer.Screen name="Login" component={LoginScreen} />
<Drawer.Screen name="Signup" component={SignupScreen} />
<Drawer.Screen name="Logout" component={LogoutScreen} />
//you can add more screens here just make sure to import them first
//example
<Drawer.Screen name="Example" component={ExampleScreen} />
// name will be the name you use to navigate to that screen
// component should have the screen you imported
```

then you should pass one of those names to props.navigation.navigate() so the button would be

```
<Button
   title="Next Page"
   onPress={() => {
      props.navigation.navigate("Login");
   }}
/>
```

Comment: Thanks this was really helpful , the button is appearing on the screen but when i try to press it i'm getting this error "The action 'NAVIGATE' with payload {"name":"ScreenName"} was not handled by any navigator.

Do you have a screen named 'ScreenName'?"                                                                                  The file is there and I tried it moving it around the directory but nothing seems to be working , do you have any  fix for this please ?

Comment: can you share the code of your navigator and the other screens you wanna navigate to

Comment: I've added the App.js to the post , the file i'm trying to  navigate to is just a simple hello world to test if the button is working.

Comment: Edited my answer to explain "yourScreenName" thing further

Comment: Yes but that just takes me to one of the screens that's in my drawer screens , what i want is to navigate to a new screen that i will create if that's possible , if not should i make a new screen in my App.js for it or ..?

Comment: yep, the navigator needs to be aware of the screens you'd like to navigate to, so you'd have to import the screen in your app.js and add it as one of the screens in your drawer navigator as i mentioned in my answer.

You can also nest multiple navigators inside each other if you want some other kind of navigator like tab or stack navigators
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/nesting-navigators/

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with a class component, then :

```
import {TouchableOpacity} from "react-native"
```

In the else part,

```
<TouchableOpacity style ={{width:100, height:100}} onPress={()=>{this.props.navigation.navigate("screenname")}}></TouchableOpacity>
```

TouchableOpacity is a blank space on the screen, which can be styled easily, and you have an onPress event. Basically it's like a better version of a button. You can also place other components inside the TouchableOpacity, and make the whole thing clickable